# Jersey / JAX-RS ExceptionMapper MySQL

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I'm in the process of learning Jersey / JAX-RS and I need a bit of help with ExceptionMapper.

I've got a UserFacade Class, AbstractFacade Class and the User class itself, all pretty standard, mostly generated from just creating a new Web Service RestFUL project with Database in Netbeans. My problem, is that I want to now start catching errors, say "Unique Constraint Violation" errors. I thought I needed to implement an exception mapper... I have the following in my facade:

```
    @Provider
    public class EntityNotFoundMapper implements ExceptionMapper {

        @Override
        public javax.ws.rs.core.Response toResponse(PersistenceException ex) {
            return Response.status(404).entity(ex.getMessage()).type("text/plain").build();
        }
    }
```

This is the error I get, that is NOT caught by my custom exception handler.

```
WARNING:   StandardWrapperValve[service.ApplicationConfig]: Servlet.service() for servlet service.ApplicationConfig threw exception
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'usernamegoeshere' for key 'username'
```

I feel like I'm close, the only reason i'm not trying to catch MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException from the example above, is because I'm just trying to catch every possible error FIRST (to make sure its working), then I'll narrow and be specific after I see that the syntax is working.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Always parametrize `ExceptionMapper`:

   ```
   public class EntityNotFoundMapper
       implements ExceptionMapper<PersistenceException> { ... }
   ```
2. [MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/mysql/jdbc/exceptions/jdbc4/MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.html) doesn't seem to be extending [PersistenceException](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceException.html). To catch `MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` you need to create an `ExceptionMapper` directly for this class or for one of it's predecessors, e.g.:

   ```
   @Provider
   public class MySqlIntegrityMapper
       implements ExceptionMapper<MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException> {

       @Override
       public Response toResponse(MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException ex) {
           return ...;
       }
   }
   ```

   or for more generic [SQLException](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html) (as `MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` inherits from it):

   ```
   @Provider
   public class SqlExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<SQLException> {

       @Override
       public Response toResponse(SQLException ex) {
           return ...;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Do you know where I might be able to find an example of how to do Part 2 of your answer?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help thus far, I feel like I'm nearly there. Now I'm getting the following error: `WARNING:   The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: HK2 service reification failed for [service.UserFacadeREST$SqlExceptionMapper] with an exception:
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Cannot instantiate service.UserFacadeREST$SqlExceptionMapper class. Instantiation of non-static member classes is not supported.`

Comment: Your `SqlExceptionMapper` is inner class in `UserFacadeREST`. Make `SqlExceptionMapper` static (`public static class SqlExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<SQLException> { ... }`) or even better make it a regular class outside of `UserFacadeREST`.

Comment: Thank you sir, I wish I could buy you a coffee or a soda or something :)